# Why is @Html.Label() removing some characters

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

When I use the following code in my razor view it renders `<label for=""> someText</label>` and not `<label for="">1. someText</label>` but I can't figure out why `1.` is removed while rendering.

```
@Html.Label(String.Format("{0}. someText",1))
```

Edit:
The following code renders `<label for="">1# someText</label>` as expected.

```
@Html.Label(String.Format("{0}# someText",1))
```

Comment: might be trying to reference an object ?!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You are misusing the [Html.Label](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg453833%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) method. It is for:

> Returns an HTML label element and the **property name of the property**
>   that is represented by the specified expression.

That's why it gets confused if you have a point `.` in the first parameter because it expects a property expression there.

However, you can use the second overload:

```
@Html.Label("", String.Format("{0}. someText",1))
```

Or just write out the HTML:

```
<label>@String.Format("{0}. someText", 1)</label>
```

Comment: that's what I thought, although you make it sound like you know what your talking about :D

Comment: What if my label text is coming from database and i don't know at which position " . " is exist ?

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid using the "Html Helper's label" and directly use html "label" and place whatever you want to display correctly. It can also save some time ;)

Answer (score 0):

The syntax which you are using is wrong or We can say that this is not a way to use property with RAZOR syntax.
You ca use this that may be help full for you.

**

```
 @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PropertyName, 
       String.Format("{0}. " + @Model.PropertyName.ToString() + ",1))
```

**

Answer (score 0):

I was using this for a data table that contained a double (Lat/Long) and saw this same problem. Thanks for the tips (I am not allowed to comment).

For me, the problem was solved ..

```
@foreach (var cell in item.ItemArray)
{
  <td>
     @Html.Label("",cell.ToString().Trim())
  </td>
 }
```