# Why does @Html.Label render an incomplete string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper

I am new to MVC4 and don't understand why @Html.Label is chopping my string data as follows.

The string returned is "11, 12.2, 15.2, 17.1R, 18.3R, 21R", and @Html.Label is chopping everything before the last . character.

View

```
<td>@foo.GetString</td>
<td>@Html.Label(foo.GetString)</td>
```

Model

```
public string GetString { get 
{ 
    return "11, 12.2, 15.2, 17.1R, 18.3R, 21R";
}
```

}

Resulting markup

```
<tr>
  <td>11, 12.2, 15.2, 17.1R, 18.3R, 21R</td>
  <td>
    <label for="">3R, 21R</label>
  </td>
</tr>
```

I am using @foo.GetString as this displays the whole string but would like to understand why this happens please.

Comment: What's happening in here: `public string GetString { get { // do stuff } }` ?

Comment: Have you tried swapping the lines around and see if the output changes. (The label would contain the full string, the @foo call would contain the limited string.) If so, that might point to an issue in your `GetString` property.

Comment: It's iterating over a List<string> using a StringBuilder and returning Stringbuilder.ToString(). Updated above.

Comment: swapping lines around makes no difference. Is this a default behaviour of @Html.Label ?

Comment: Possible duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10227775/why-is-html-label-removing-some-characters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the LabelHelper method of `LabelExtensions` class. [source](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/LabelExtensions.cs)

```
internal static MvcHtmlString LabelHelper(HtmlHelper html, ModelMetadata metadata,
               string htmlFieldName, string labelText = null, 
               IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes = null)
        {
            string resolvedLabelText = labelText ?? metadata.DisplayName 
                 ?? metadata.PropertyName 
                 ?? htmlFieldName.Split('.').Last();
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(resolvedLabelText))
            {
                return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
            }

            TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("label");
            tag.Attributes.Add("for", TagBuilder.CreateSanitizedId(
                html.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(htmlFieldName)));
            tag.SetInnerText(resolvedLabelText);
            tag.MergeAttributes(htmlAttributes, replaceExisting: true);
            return tag.ToMvcHtmlString(TagRenderMode.Normal);
        }
```

As you can see, it finds the last dot in the field's name `htmlFieldName.Split('.').Last()` to make the `resolvedLabelText` in your case. So you should not use it for displaying the raw data. Its main usage is displaying `metadata.DisplayName` or `metadata.PropertyName`.

You can try `@Html.Raw` to show the content as it is (without any kinds of encoding).

Answer (score 0):

My solution is:

```
<label id=@("label_" + Model.Name) for=@("textBox_" + Model.Name)>@(Model.Caption)</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use second overload method of @Html.Label as below:

@Html.Label("", foo.GetString)

which will give you expected result.