# Peculiar error while displaying error message in a MVC view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am trying to display error message in a `View` based on `ViewBag` status. But the thing is whenever i put a full stop(.) in the error message, error message before (.) is not displayed. It goes like this:

```
@if (@ViewBag.ProfileStatus == 0)
{ 
@Html.Label("Error generating Report. Please try again ! ", new { id = "lblStatus" })
}
```

Output:

```
Please try again !
```

Again if message is:

```
@if (@ViewBag.ProfileStatus == 0)
{ 
@Html.Label("Error generating Report..!! ", new { id = "lblStatus" })
}
```

Output:

```
!!
```

Please, can anyone explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the secondary overload, this will solve your issue:

```
@Html.Label("", String.Format("{0}. Please try again !","Error generating Report"))
```

More info at the following [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10227775/why-is-html-label-removing-some-characters)